# A Raphael.js compound path with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I have an animation where several paths are transformed in the same way. I would like to make it more efficient by greating a single compound path and applying the transformation only once. The problem is that the paths are a different color. Using a set or array will not help because it is not more efficient than using seperate paths. How do I do this?

*For a set paper.set( paper.path('M0,0 4,0 0,4z'),paper.path('M9,9 4,9 9,4z') );, an equivalent compound path would be paper.path('M0,0 4,0 0,4z M9,9 4,9 9,4z');.*

Comment: Not sure its possible to do what you want, without some other workaround, and there's not really enough info on the animation for that.

Comment: In SVG, it is not possible to have multi-coloured paths. I'm afraid you will have to stick with multiple paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Snap.svg. It was built on the same engine of Raphael by dimitri (the guy who created rephael). It supports grouping which will give you what you are looking for. The migration from Raphael to Snap.svg is very simple and almost requires no modification.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. The only downside is that Snap.svg doesn't support browsers older than IE 9

Comment: Plus it doesn't work very well with IE11 either which is a modern browser that you should support for...

Comment: well... that's true, but sadly to my knowledge what you are asking for is 100% not achievable with Raphael. I migrated to Snap for a very similar reason.